# What is the "bluffer's group" called?

Tags: group-theory, terminology, semidirect-product

Today I attended a course on Geometric Group Theory in Spanish, and we saw an example of a group which could be literally translated as "bluffer's group", because there is a funny way to interpret it. The group is the following:

$\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}[t,t^{-1}]\rtimes \langle t\rangle$

Where the product is defined by

$(p(t), t^m)(q(t),t^n)=(p(t)+t^mq(t),t^{m+n})$.

What's the actual name of this group in English?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamplighter_group

Comment: Thanks! @QiaochuYuan

Comment: Can I ask you why it is called the "bluffer's group" in spanish?

Comment: @AnalysisStudent0414 I might have translated the word wrong, but the spanish word means the same as "lamplighter"